# Threads Blocked in SOAP WS getPort() - Performace issues + High CPU

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I have created Java classes using WSDL and then calling SOPA WS. Everything works fine in low load but as the load increases Threads start going to BLOCKED state.

CPU is also very high. On analysing Thread dump seems some contention `sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile` lock.

Code for calling SOAP endpoint

```
Service service = new Service();
UMarket uMarketSC = service.getUMarketSC(); // Getting pport
setEndpoint(uMarketSC, wsdlUrl);

public static void setEndpoint(Object port, String newAddress) {
    BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider)port;
    Map<String, Object> context = bp.getRequestContext();
    context.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,newAddress);

    context.put(SOAP_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, systemSettings.getExternalAdapterConnectionTimeout());
    context.put(SOAP_READ_TIMEOUT, systemSettings.getExternalAdapterReadTimeout());
}
```

[image: Thread Dump Analysis]

Stacktrace of a BLOCKED thread:-

```
qtp358249583-788 - priority:5 - threadId:0x00007fe5d8098800 - 
nativeId:0x57d6 - state:BLOCKED
stackTrace:
java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:702)
- waiting to lock <0x0000000721f63d10> (a sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:732)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(DataInputStream.java:337)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:589)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.bytecode.ClassTailor.tailor(ClassTailor.java:131)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.tailor(AccessorInjector.java:107)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.prepare(AccessorInjector.java:68)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.OptimizedAccessorFactory.get(OptimizedAccessorFactory.java:164)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$FieldReflection.optimize(Accessor.java:271)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.<init>(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:79)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor157.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:113)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:166)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:488)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:305)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:124)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1123)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:147)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.api.JAXBRIContext.newInstance(JAXBRIContext.java:152)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.api.JAXBRIContext.newInstance(JAXBRIContext.java:96)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.JAXBContextFactory$1.createJAXBContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:98)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.glassfish.JAXBRIContextFactory.newContext(JAXBRIContextFactory.java:79)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.db.BindingContextFactory.create(BindingContextFactory.java:167)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:203)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:176)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:176)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.postProcess(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:95)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:309)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.<init>(DatabindingImpl.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:59)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:43)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingFactoryImpl.createRuntime(DatabindingFactoryImpl.java:105)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.buildRuntimeModel(WSServiceDelegate.java:875)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createSEIPortInfo(WSServiceDelegate.java:892)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.addSEI(WSServiceDelegate.java:855)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:435)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:404)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:386)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:119)
```

Comment: How do you know the problem isn't with the endpoint?

Comment: If you are saying that threads are blocked because of endpoint then that is not the casr because downstream service returns the response without delay

Comment: Also then there will be timeouts..why the thread is getting blocked?

Comment: Ok so you've verified that the endpoints are returning immediately even under load. Right?

Comment: @D-Klotz yes...researching on SOAP i found out getPort has some Performance issues.But still figuring out how to solve, probably some kind of pooling.

Comment: Just had a thought. How fast are these transactions and are you doing 100s, 10s of thousands or millions of transactions per minute? Meaning how long does a transaction stay active before it is complete?

Comment: @D-Klotz Right now target is of around 25TPS only and it is  breaking even before that . I dont have expertise in SOAP so cant say much. Every call takes around 400ms to complete.

Comment: Do you think is there anything fundamentally wrong in the way I am callling SOAP? I cant find any other way of calling SOAP.

Comment: Process of elimination for the moment. In the past I had an issue with SOAP and heavy object creation that I fixed by using the java 8 options such as these `-XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` but I'm not sure that's your issue. I've also had success connecting VisualVM to the server and learning where the server is spending its time..

Comment: Thanks for the update. But i am already using `-XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` , I read somewhere that JDK has a bug in Zip file, so trying out with JDK 10. Will update if I am able to resolve.